# Poltergeist/PhantomJS not honoring client-side redirect

Tags: phantomjs, poltergeist

Most of my automated integration test suite relies on a third-party authentication system that uses a client-side redirect, over which I have no control:

```
if (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) { SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.handleRedirect('https://example.com/?authtoken=MYTOKEN&more_stuff=etc'); }  
else if (window.location.replace){ 
window.location.replace('https://example.com/?authtoken=MYTOKEN&more_stuff=etc');
} else {;
window.location.href ='https://example.com/?authtoken=MYTOKEN&more_stuff=etc';
}
```

For some reason, Poltergeist/PhantomJS is stopping here and not honoring the redirect code. Is this because it's trying to use `window.location.replace` or `window.location.href` instead of `window.location` directly?

Here's my Poltergeist configuration in RSpec:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_tls do |app|
    poltergeist_options = {
        js_errors: true,
        phantomjs_options: ['--ssl-protocol=TLSv1.2']
    }
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, poltergeist_options)
end
```

Here's a simplified version of my spec:

```
it 'logs the user in', js: true do
    visit login_url
    fill_in 'Email', with: email
    fill_in 'Password', with: password
    find('input[value="LOG IN"]').click()
    expect(page).to have_selector '#logout-btn'
 end
```

I'm using Capybara 2.7.1, Poltergeist 1.10.0, and PhantomJS 2.1.1.

**Edit:** I know that `window.location` was broken in PhantomJS once upon a time but that appears to have been [fixed](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/5eb0f64e6b) years ago.

However, when I add this to my spec:

```
#hackishly get the redirect URL
matches = page.body.match(%r{window.location.href ='(https?://.*)';})
redirect_url = matches[1]
evaluate_script("window.location = '#{redirect_url}'")
evaluate_script('console.log(window.location)')
```

...it's still outputting the old `window.location` instead of the newly set `redirect_url`. Huh??

Comment: put `sleep 3` after the click and then check `page.driver.network_traffic` to see what is actually being sent/received by poltergeist

Comment: thanks, I'll try that